# Are bots asking seemingly valid questions?

Tags: discussion, spam

This is regarding the deleted question, [Java - comparing pixels to a given value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41912819/java-comparing-pixels-to-a-given-value). User efekctive posted [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41913142/522444), but then quickly deleted it and [posted in comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41912819/java-comparing-pixels-to-a-given-value#comment71007735_41912819), "I am deleting my answer. Some of these posts seem to be made by bots", a comment that was up-voted. But this did not appear to be the case to me, and so I have to ask, am I missing something? Has there been a rash of authentic-appearing questions created and posted by bots lately? Does this question (or the comments) look suspicious? Note that the OP then deleted the question, perhaps due to is having received a down-vote.

Sorry for asking about a deleted question since many here can't see it.

Here's an image of the question:

[image]

Comment: "Sorry for asking about a deleted question" Why be sorry for talking about a deleted post when you provide a screenshot of it?

Comment: @dorukayhan: even with a screen shot, some folks can't see all involved with the post, including all comments and the deleted answer. For brevity's sake, I did not post these. Thanks for your comment though as it helps me to clarify that point.

Comment: No, that question was not posted by a bot. I'm not sure who upvoted that comment, but I see no evidence.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: thanks. I just wanted to make sure that my "bot radar" didn't need to be re-calibrated.

Comment: One comment upvote does not a fact make! :-)

Comment: That sounds like something a bot would say...

Comment: @ivarni: `+++Divide By Cucumber Error. Please Reinstall Universe And Reboot +++`

Comment: [obligatory xkcd reference](https://xkcd.com/810/)

Comment: I think this is just _"efekctive"_ being pi55y.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I see no evidence, whatsoever, that bots are posting questions on Stack Overflow, certainly not for that specific user.

I'm not sure who upvoted that comment, but it's not based on any facts that I can discover.

Comment: [Bots have posted answers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/283095/135615), but they didn't do a particularly good job of it. Their answers were based on cobbling together information from similar questions, so it would be a step beyond that to start formulating questions, particularly well-received ones.

Comment: Fwiw, though, while I don't have any links handy, I've also seen bots post question / answer pairs in the past. Something about them makes them not *impossible* to spot but they can be tricky. Typically what they do is copy a question directly from another forum or Q&A site, then later post an answer that either contains a spam link, or is a somewhat modified copy of a response to the original copied question that contains a spam link. I haven't seen one in a long time, though. I remember a run of them a year or two ago.

Comment: @JasonC: I'm not 100% convinced they were bots; the content could easily have been human-curated to target SO. The *posting* could have been handled by bots, in the sense that they are part of a botnet to evade blocking of the spammers primary IP addresses. As you noted, the content was plagiarised, *not generated*.

Comment: Yeah that makes more sense. Who knows. Spam is very mysterious to me.